# What is a 3 wire type cross linked serial cable?

Tags: serial, rs232, db9

I'm trying to use a controller which uses Serial communication with the PC. The documentation says I need to get a 3 wire type cross link serial cable.  Is this a null modem cable?

The following image is from the documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - I would call that a Null Modem cable.

If the cable you get (or make) doesn't work, my first debugging step for serial communications is to swap connections on pins 2 and 3. (Transmit and Receive data)

Comment: I would be hesitant to call that a Null Modem cable.  A typical Null Modem cable is female-female (in addition to being crossed).

Comment: Null-modem + gender-changer. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

Since the TXD (3) of one side is connected with the RXD (2) of the other, this is indeed a null-modem cable. Normal serial cables have pins 2 and 3 connected straight through, and the [DCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_circuit-terminating_equipment) is responsible for cross-connecting them internally.

Comment: It should also connect RTS/CTS and DSR/DTR signals on both ends together to mimic a communication-ready device on the other end. However, this is not needed if the application doesn't rely on hardware flow control.

Answer (score 2):

Whether it is a null-modem cable depends on your definition. Yours can be described as a partial null-modem cable, in that it does not incorporate hardware flow control. Or, since most PCs these days don't require flow control, it can be called a null-modem cable. Your documentation is being correct by specifying a three-wire cable, but a full-up null-modem would also work. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_modem for a description of the possibilities.

Additionally, as Nick Alexeyev has commented, a null-modem cable usually has connectors of the same gender, since standard RS232 distinguishes between a Data Terminal Equipment (DTE) box and a Data Circuit-Terminating Equipment (DCE) box, and these are distinguished be different connector genders. So the cable you show is not technically a null-modem cable, but rather a crossover cable without flow-control - in other words, a cross-linked 3-wire cable. Add a gender changer, and it becomes what is nowadays called a null-modem in the PC world.

Answer (score 1):

Some background.

RS-232 serial ports were originally designed to connect a modem (DCE) to a teleprinter (DTE). There was a data line in each direction and also a number of lines for handshake and modem control. Later computers, graphical terminals etc got serial ports too, again these were used for connecting to modems and so used DTE pinouts. The DTE was connected to the DCE using a "straight through" cable..

Sometimes it was desirable to connect a computer to a terminal or a computer to a computer or even a terminal to a terminal without using any modems. So cables known as "null modems" got made-up. These crossed over the data lines allowing the two DTE devices to be connected together. What they did with the handshake lines varied. Some looped them back, some crossed them in various ways, some didn't connect them at all. In later years most null modem cables seemed to settle on connecting the RTS output on each end to the CTS input on the other and also connecting the DTR output on each end to both the DSR and DCD inputs on the other.

---

The cable described in your instructions can be regarded as a primitive form of null-modem cable with only the data connectors and ground present. It also has an unusual combination of connector genders.

So the question then becomes:

> can I use a regular null modem cable and a gender changer to connect this device to my PC? or do I need to find/make a special cable to thier specs.

And the answer is most likely yes but there is the outside possibility that the manufacturer has done something stupid and you really do need a cable that ONLY has the data pins and ground present.